# Why Iraqi embassy websites closed for 1 month already?

Tags: iraq, embassy

I have recently noticed Iraqi embassy websites throughout the world have been closed out. Their foreign affairs website has pages for these embassies but not fully available websites . Here are some sample links

http://mofamission.gov.iq/en/EmiDubai

Comment: For that specific domain, `traceroute mofamission.gov.iq` gives an unknown host error, which is to say that the DNS servers (Azure, in this case) that are configured to map the domain to an IP address aren't aware of any server for the domain. Presumably someone misconfigured something somewhere and no one has noticed yet.